# Making a new angle from given angles.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We know how to draw some angles.We are also able to draw the angles after performing addition and subtraction operation on known angles.Suppose there are n number of known angles and k queries, where a new angle is given and it is asked to draw that following above strategy, you need to tell is it possible  to draw that new angle from known angle after performing some operations on known angles.

Example:

n=2  // number of known angles

k=4  // number of queries

100,70 // known angles

240,40,130,127 // new angles

240 is possible as  100+70+70

40 is possible as 100+100+100+100-360

130 is possible as 100+100-70

127 is not possible

Comment: it is from a contes that is no more live. http://www.hackerearth.com/druva-hiring-challenge/algorithm/angles-2/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a solution of a Diophantine equation. A new angle $\beta$ is expressible with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots$ if

$$\alpha_1a_1+\alpha_2 a_2+\cdots=\beta$$

has integer solutions for $a_1,\ldots$.

This is very straight-forward, if your angles are in rational proportions. If two angles have irrational proportions, the equation is ill-defined as a Diophantine equation.

After stating above equation, all the theory of linear Diophantine equations can be used.